# Are there any known songs for guitar hero?

Tags: guitar-hero

I got Guitar Hero 5 and I'm in shock. There is like 4 songs that I know:

- Du Hast
- Ring of fire (one of the best songs, but that just shows the level of songs)
- Ex-Girlfriend (I don't like it, but the level of songs is very low)
- Nirvana's Teen Spirit

Other songs are not for me and I don't care about them. There are some known bands, but they only have unknown songs. Is there some Guitar Hero with better song list?

For example *No Doubt* has a lot of good songs, but here there is only *Ex-Girlfriend*. I think everybody will agree that its not one of the best songs they have made.

Does any other version of GH have better song selection?

I'm not asking for Linkin Park or any other really known band, but just for songs that everybody will enjoy (including me, I'm more of pop person).

Comment: Asking for games with a better long list is game rec, and as such off-topic. It could be edited to no longer be a game rec, by making it a question asking for a list of Rock band / GH long lists, but that's an example of a "bad list", since any answer would need to be updated everytime a new DLC / game was released.

Comment: hey @IAdapter, you seem to be on a streak! of closed questions. Is everything alright?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Guitar Hero:

  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero_II)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero_III:_Legends_of_Rock)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: World Tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero_World_Tour)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: Metallica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero:_Metallica)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero:_Warriors_of_Rock)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: Aerosmith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero:_Aerosmith)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: Smash Hits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_Hero_Smash_Hits#Soundtrack)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: Rocks the 80s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Guitar_Hero_Encore:_Rocks_the_80s)
  - [List of songs in Guitar Hero: Van Halen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guitar_Hero:_Van_Halen#Soundtrack)
- Rock Band:

  - [List of songs in Rock Band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rock_band_songs#Main_setlist)
  - [List of songs in Rock Band 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Rock_Band_2)
  - [List of songs in Rock Band: The Beatles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_The_Beatles:_Rock_Band)
  - [List of songs in Rock Band 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_songs_in_Rock_Band_3)
  - [List of songs in Band Hero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_Hero#Soundtrack)

Comment: thx, that will be very helpful :)

Comment: I found GH3 had the best "selection" based on what I know.

Comment: I would add Band Hero to the list, given that the OP mentioned liking pop music.

Comment: Original Guitar Hero ftw

Comment: As mentioned by Dave, Band Hero definitely has more pop songs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_Hero#Soundtrack

Comment: lol@YMCA in Band Hero. Truth be told, I had never even heard of that game before...

Answer (score 5):

In Addition to the great answer Ragnar gave you also have the DLC for Rock Band

[List of DLC songs in Rockband](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_list_of_downloadable_songs_for_the_Rock_Band_series)

Comment: This.  If you're more of a pop person you need Rock Band, not Guitar Hero...

Answer (score 2):

With these sorts of games, you should really make your purchase decision based on the one that has the best track listing for you.

And an alternative way to look at it, which I took, was to use it as a way to get to know some more bands. I knew most of the songs, but when I found some new ones I liked, I went and bought their albums.

Have to admit I like them so much I have GH1,2,3 and Aerosmith, RB1 and 2 and once I get some free time I am getting RB3 as well.

They have made me some good prizes in competitions so I love 'em all